# Z3-str/Z3str2: can it be used in conjunction with the rest of Z3?

Tags: z3, smt

We need a string-solver and are considering Z3-str or its successor Z3str2. Can these extensions simultaneously be used in conjunction with all the rest of Z3 (i.e. all other theory solvers implemented in Z3)? Or are these string-extensions only usable quasi standalone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, no.  Trying to declare a real using Z3-str gives an error.  It seems that only strings and ints are supported.

There are other things to consider before using Z3-str as well.  It seems to require a slightly different, non SMT-LIB v2 compliant input format.  There are example files provided in `Z3-str/tests/`.  They use, for example `declare-variable` to declare variables rather than `declare-const` or `declare-fun`.

There's also some ambiguity in the project about the difference between Z3-str and Z3-str2.  Specifically, if you go to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/z3str/Z3-str) then `Z3-str2.py` is referenced in the build instructions, but there is no such file in the repo, only `Z3-str.py`. I think what is on the GitHub page is nonetheless the most recent version, because there are commits from Feb 2016.

Finally, Z3-str [apparently uses a deprecated API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616645/z3python-stringsort-support), so you have to use an old  version of Z3. So you might not want to build a new project around Z3-str unless you can deal with using Z3 4.1.1 (October 2012).

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky: Z3 currently natively support strings.
Of course, strings can be combined with all other theories.